# Oracle UCM site id of a site - how to modify?

Tags: oracle, oracle-ucm

How to modify the site id of a site in Oracle UCM? If I have a site "monica" and I want to rename it to "monica_new", how can I change this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the sitename_project.xml file which will have the all the site aspects.There you can see the site-id and site-name properties which you can change and test.